# Is "anymore" a word?

Tags: word-usage, orthography, dictionaries

Quite often when I type the word "anymore" in software featuring built-in spell check, I get the following kind of warning:

[image]

(this one is courtesy of [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)).

i.e., the "anymore" word gets underlined as if it didn't exist. I'm not a native speaker, so every time I see the above, I'm in doubt.

**Is "anymore" a word?**

*Grammarly* seems to agree:

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/anymore-vs-any-more/

But then why on earth aren't software dictionaries up to date? I mean, *anymore* doesn't look like an esoteric word that would rarely be used, so I would expect, if the warning was a false positive, that it would have been quickly reported and corrected already?

Could it be that it's valid in BE, and not in AE, or the other way around?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/any-more-or-anymore

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/anymore

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anymore

Comment: https://writingexplained.org/anymore-vs-any-more-difference

Comment: @HotLicks I do understand the *difference*, and have always used "any more" and "anymore" this way, but every time I see the latter highlighted, I wonder if "anymore" is correct usage or just a commonly accepted language deformation. As for your links above, I understand from the first two links that this is US English. Merriam Webster doesn't say, nor does WritingExplained, but I suspect them to be US. Should I understand that I'm getting this warning because I'm using a UK dictionary, and that "anymore" is not valid usage in British English?

Comment: In the first link given by Hot Licks it says "Especially in American English, any more, as an adverb, can be written as one word, anymore:

He doesn’t cycle anymore."  I was quite surprised at the frequency difference between the two when comparing on Google NGrams. These spell checkers must be pedantic ones. From writingexplained.com "In British English, it is still quite common to see any more (two words) as an adverb in print. This is beginning to change, however, as some British writers and publishing houses opt to observe the distinction between the one-word and two-word spellings."

Comment: In my MS Word "anymore" is accepted, but in LibreOffice Writer is underlines it in red, just depends what spell checker you have. I don't know who'll still insist on keeping "anymore" as two separate words.

Comment: What I would surmise is either your settings are for British English (BrE), which rejects the use of "anymore" and only accepts "any more," or it's an accidental omission in your app's spellcheck.  Try to use "alright." If that gets rejected, then I'd say your settings or your dictionary is BrE.

Comment: The third answer in the above linked question mentions the BrE and AmE difference in preference, or should I say the UK and rest-of-the-world difference in preference, I don't know.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman If you mean British English in the broader sense, that's not true. Even in the strict sense (in Great Britain) it's not true.

Comment: You certainly wouldn't say "UK and rest-of-the-world difference in preference" because "anymore" is nonstandard in various English-speaking places outside of the UK.  It's also not a *preference* in the UK as BrE rejects the use of "anymore" appearing as one word instead of two as being ungrammatical.

Comment: @Zebrafish - I don't know what you're getting at with "it," and as for BrE, it only has one sense.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Just go to the BBC website and search for "anymore" and you'll see how nonstandard it is. I'm surprised there's surprise about this, must have been a quick development.

Comment: The fact that there are Brits who've employed this Americanism in their writing doesn't make it standard.  While English grammar is descriptive, it's descriptive in the sense that it describes how people speak.  The difference between "anymore" and "any more" is merely textual, and Oxford's grammarians, the deciders of how that spoken word shall appear, continue to reject "anymore" as standard English.  In Britain, the standard is Queen's English.  That's what BrE is.  There's no "preference" involved as that's the only standard.  And that standard disallows "anymore," labeling it nonstandard.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman You can spend as long as you like seeing how common its acceptance is in British English. Collins Dictionary note: "In British English, the spelling anymore is sometimes considered incorrect, and any more is used instead." It's recognized at what used to by Oxford Online Living Dictionaries at Lexico and other BrE dictionaries I've checked.

Comment: @Zebrafish - The question is about why spellcheck has underlined it.  This is why.  You may not like the reason.  You may argue that because so many Brits employ the Americanism "anymore" in their writing it should be standard.  But the fact of the matter is it's not.  And the fact of the matter is that's why it's underlined.  That's the answer to the question.  Your philosophical disagreement has no bearing on the actual reason why "anymore" is getting underlined by BrE spellchecks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, guys. Now I know that's it's the rule in AE, but in BE I should write "any more" in both cases. Could someone write an answer?

Comment: Have a look at this Ngram - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anymore%2C+any+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canymore%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cany%20more%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Canymore%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cany%20more%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Benjamin - Yes, in formal communication in BrE, you are to use "any more" always, lest you risk getting frowned upon for employing nonstandard English⁠— or even worse, an Americanism, egads!

Comment: @BenjaminHarman But it's in BrE dictionaries. It's in Collins, it's in Oxford at lexico.com, it's in Macmillan, it's in Cambridge, it's in Longman. It's used in British journalism, just do a search in The Guardian or the BBC. It's not true to say it's nonstandard today.

Comment: In case you're deciding which way you should write it, here are some corpus results for how often we see "any more" and "anymore" in different parts of the world. Scroll down to the table. This information is from 2015 from the Oxford English Corpus. https://jeremybutterfield.wordpress.com/2015/11/06/3291/

Comment: @Zebrafish - Informal words are in dictionaries. You can find "ain't" in a British dictionary, but that doesn't make it standard English or fit for formal writing. If you are accessing lexico.com from a US IP address, it's giving you AmE.  If you look in *Collins*, it expressly labels "anymore" as "US" and puts beside it the letters "UK" followed by "any more." Again, Queen's English establishes the "standard" for BrE, so you can argue and argue there are British people who use it, even journals, but that doesn't change the fact Queen's English rejects it, making it nonstandard in BrE. Period.

Comment: @Zebrafish - And, YET AGAIN, you're arguing and arguing and arguing about what should be or whatever, but the OP's question is about "anymore" getting underlined by spellcheck, specifically in British English versus American English, and this is why. It gets underlined by British spellcheck apps because those apps are saying it's nonstandard. That's the reason. You can argue that it's standard or should be until you're blue in the face, but that's irrelevant since it doesn't change the reason it's getting underlined, which is the entire point of all these comments: to explain why.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman No, it gets underlined because the particular dictionary the software uses doesn't recognize it. Most of the modern BrE dictionaries recognize the word, that's just fact. Collins online DOES accept it, and makes the note "the spelling anymore is sometimes considered incorrect". IP addresses don't figure into this at all as the same results are gotten with a UK IP. It is NOT nonstandard, unlike "ain't", which IS labelled as such by many dictionaries.  And saying "Queen's English rejects it" is just ridiculous. Where does it say in "Queen's English" that it's nonstandard today?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - There is often a noticeable spoken difference between "anymore" and "any more".